# In Flutter How to pass image from one class to other?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, imagepicker

How to pass image picked from file from one activity to other in flutter...

I am using this code to picked image from gallery.

```
File? image;



Future pickImage() async {
    try {
      final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (image == null) return;
      final imageTemp = File(image.path);
      setState(() => this.image = imageTemp);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print('Failed to pick image: $e');
    }
  }
```

I want to pass the variable named image to other class. on button click

Comment: what do you mean by class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - I want to pass variable from one class to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50702749/flutter-i-want-to-pass-variable-from-one-class-to-another)

Comment: also, duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71006599/passing-image-from-one-screen-to-another-flutter

Comment: also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53861302/passing-data-between-screens-in-flutter

Comment: @OMiShah when i use this method my app gets error.

Comment: @MunsifAli from one layout to other

Comment: what's error are you facing?

Comment: @MunsifAli i can not user XFile.

Comment: @EhsanAbid, post the error message/screenshot you're getting.

Comment: @OMiShah i can not run the file because it says you can not user XFile.  and when I use only File it says file can not b empty and I am also addich check of not null but still showing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your class as below on which you want to pass image variable,

```
 class ClassOther extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  stateClassOther createState() => stateClassOther();
  File image;
  ClassOther({required this.image});
  }
```